# Reorganizing Ruby URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my Ruby on Rails web application, I have the files:

```
app/models/big.rb
app/controllers/big_controller.rb
app/models/small.rb
app/controllers/small_controller.rb
```

Links such as `http://localhost:8080/big/1` and `http://localhost:8080/small/` work great but I want to be able to have a link such as

```
http://localhost:8080/big/1/small
```

How do I set up routes to do this? I would like to not have to go through and update all paths (ex. `small_path`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (nested routes/resources)

```
resources :big do
  resources :small
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Does it matter where in my routes.rb I put this?

Comment: @CodeGuy no it does not matter where you put this in your routes. So long as your set up is like the example provided above and on the links it should be fine and no you will not have to go through and update all your paths as Rails maps all the resources for you and take care of it

Comment: @CodeGuy Yes, your routes now have changed: where you had called e.g. `edit_small_path(@small)`, you will now have to call `edit_big_small_path(@small.big, @small)` (`link_to 'edit', [:edit, @small.big, @small]` should work as well). To work around this non-DRY-ish behaviour, add an extra route `resources :small` to your routes, then you can keep your URL helper calls (but then again, you don't have nested routes).